# Can I use Func<object[], object> represent any kind of parameters input and TResult?

Tags: c#, .net, delegates, func

Can I have a generic delegation Func to represent any delegation input and result?
Such as

```
public static int ProcessJob(Func<object[], object> function, params object[] args)
```

I call this function as follows:

```
Func<int, string> Test = TestFunction;
AsyncJobHelper.ProcessJob(Test, i);
```

VS2010 gave me error on this.

Comment: No, your Func will accept ONE parameter of type object[], not a variable number of parameters as params keyword does (but it's what a simple (untyped) Delegate can do...

Comment: a non generic generic :-S

Comment: I could make it using lambda expressions and a simple `Func<TResult>`, check answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No; you can't do that.

Instead, you can make your function take the base `Delegate` class and call `DynamicInvoke()`.
Note that this uses reflection and will be slow.

Comment: See Adriano's answer:
int ProcessJob(Delegate func, params object[] args) { func.DynamicInvoke(args); /* ... */ } is more than enough.

Answer (score 2):

maybe generic ProcessJob is what you need

```
public static TResult ProcessJob<TInput,TResult>(Func<TInput[],TResult> function, params TInput[] args)
 {
    return function(args);
 }
```

Comment: No, here generics will just force you to have the same type for all parameters, it won't make the delegate "variable length".

Comment: Why not? Delegate takes the arrray of TInputs as argument, that can be variable length. This is ok: ProcessJob(a=>a.Lenght,"1","2","3","4"). But im not sure that i understand the OPs requirement correctly.

Comment: Yes because "params object[]" can be passed to "object[]" but you cant assign "int foo(string)" to that delegate (this is the OP's problem, he/she would have a typed delegate for a variable parameters length function).

Comment: `int ProcessJob(Delegate func, params object[] args) { func.DynamicInvoke(args); /* ... */ }` is more than enough.

Answer (score 0):

I did that in another way:

```
public static T ProcessJob<T>(Func<T> function)
```

And to call, I instance the function with a lambda expression:

```
Func<string> Test = () => return TestFunction(Param1, Param2, Param3);
AsyncJobHelper.ProcessJob(Test);
```

See? The lambda expression accepts as many params as your `TestFunction` needs.

Comment: I don't think this would compile. The lambda you assign to Test is not a `Func<string>`.